# VSTS has been renamed to Azure Devops

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The meta.SO has already addressed the proposed resolutions, but I think the outcome should be reflected here to avoid confusion.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373920/vsts-has-been-renamed-to-azure-devops-lets-talk-about-some-tags?cb=1

Comment: Thanks for the head up, I'll check with Tim or other CM how to handle that here.

Comment: I don't suppose there is any controversy in changing the tags here, but if so, we can easily reverse the naming or create a new synonym.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [convention on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373920/1438) I renamed:

```
vsts-build -> azure-pipelines
vsts -> azure-devops
```

Those were the only two `vsts*` tags I see. It would be good if someone edited (or suggested an edit) to the tag wikis for <s>[azure-devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tags/azure-devops/info)</s> (Now done) and created one for [azure-pipelines](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tags/azure-pipelines/info).